# Incoming SMS with Python SMPP

Tags: python, sms-gateway, smpp

I'm an new to using SMPP. I am not quite sure incoming messages works. I am implementing this in Python 2.7 using smpplib.I was able to connect to the SMPP service and send out SMS using a bind_transmitter.

In the example there is a function call recv_handler, however I don't see it call for anywhere. Here is the function:

```
    def recv_handler(self, **args):
        print 'Message received:', args
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

I know this question is a bit old. But for someone who lands here looking how to deal with incoming SMS you can get started quickly [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey):

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_monkey():

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.message("Hello, Mobile Monkey")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am no longer working on this project. I can't verify that it is working, but thank you for the answer and I hope it is helpful to anyone who comes across it.